# Is it possible to load data over proxy in flex

Tags: apache-flex, proxy, loading

I'm wondering if it's possible to load assets through proxy in flex,
for example to load image.

As far as I discovered there isn't such way, but I thought it wouldn't be any harm to examine your huge knowledge also :).

Thanks, 
Royee

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that is what you want, but you can use [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/) as a proxy for your Flex application.

Comment: 10x for but this is not what I need.
BTW - use it a lot and its great.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can, I am just after looking for a Flex proxy for accessing XML and Image data, and happened upon this [blog article](http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2007/05/31/php-proxy-script-for-cross-domain-requests/) (with sample code) from www.abdulqabiz.com. Lovely stovely!